# Errors when trying to reference file in cypress

Tags: javascript, typescript, automation, cypress

I have saved email and password in a .json file and I am attempting to reference it and use a fixture function to fill the content. Everytime I do this cypress throws me an error shown below

TypeError: Cannot read property 'myUser' of undefined

I have tried to put into a beforeEach and it's own separate function but it doesn't seem to work

import {mainPage} from "../pageObjects/mainPage";
import {signInPage} from "../pageObjects/signInPage";

describe("Signing into FT", () => {

```
before(() => {
    cy.visit("/")
    cy.get(mainPage.acceptCookies).contains("Accept").click();
    cy.fixture('accessInfo.json').as('myUser');
});

before(() => {
    cy.fixture('accessInfo.json').as('myUser');
})

it('Signing into FT',() => {
    cy.get(signInPage.navigateToSignInPage).click();
    cy.get(signInPage.enterEmail).type(this.myUser.email);
    cy.get(signInPage.enterEmailNext).click();
})
```

})

I am expecting a solution to just reference my fields i've specified in the .json file. My current solution could be completely wrong at the moment

Comment: Using `this` to retrieve aliases should work if you are inside a non-arrow function instead of arrow function (then `this` is set according to caller context and not inherited lexically from parent scope). As docs say https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#this-context

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use fixtures like that. Basically you have to login inside your cy.fixture as it has promise chain context. (or) you have to read the entire JSON file in constant variable and access throughout your tests.

Use below code snippet, which will work like charm.

```
it('Signing into FT', () => {
cy.get(signInPage.navigateToSignInPage).click();
  cy.fixture("fixtures.json").then((credentials) => {
    cy.get(signInPage.enterEmail).type(credentials.email);
    cy.get(signInPage.enterPassword).type(credentials.password);
  });
})
```

Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: This worked for me thank you, just had to change the fixture file name and it worked without any issues

Comment: Does that mean you have given incorrect name earlier...however I am still wondering how your script worked, as I can see there is no context share of cy.fixture to your it block....